.SPL and .SHD stuck in Spools folder
The only workaround I have been able to come up with is making a copy of the same .SPL file and pasting it back into the Spools folder. After that it processes. This is a virtual printer. The print job is coming from a user's computer being sent to our forms print server that uses Patient Works to process the forms jobs and then sends it to the associated printer at their location. So the print driver is just "Generic /Text Only". What I would like to try to understand is why making a copy of the same .SPL allows it to process, but the original does not?
Last KB Update: KB5039217
